# high cpu consumption by sbt main thread when running a project with nohup

Tags: java, sbt, playframework-2.1, nohup

To get right to it, I am trying to build an autonomous environment where I can provide the benefits of sbt's auto-reloading without needing to actually run interactively. At this point I have a setup that does exactly what I want with the exception of the sbt main thread going crazy and eating 100% cpu. I am unsure of why this is the case, but because this is an unusual way of doing things I wanted to discuss it here before filing a bug.

First, some system information.

- CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
- java version "1.7.0_51"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
- sbt (launched with 0.13.0, but the project then runs under 0.12.4)

I am orchestrating this system using chef, the script that kicks everything off will be run as root and here is what the constructed command for a particular project looks like. If this command is decomposed and run as hubuser without background and nohup, i.e. the normal way as an interactive shell, everything works exactly as would be expected.

```
su - hubuser -c "cd /home/hubuser/projects/cruise/tsttravel_synced; nohup java -Xms512M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -Xmx4096M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/hubuser/projects/cruise -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9054 -Dnet.tstllc.rmi.agent.port=9104 -javaagent:/opt/tst/jmx/jmx-agent.jar -jar /home/hubuser/projects/sbt-launch.jar 'project cruise-web' ';compile;run -Dhttp.port=9004 -Dap.credentials.file=/home/hubuser/projects/credentials.cfg -Dap.config.file=/home/hubuser/projects/app.cfg -Dlogger.file=/home/hubuser/projects/cruise/cruise-logback.xml' &>> /home/hubuser/projects/cruise/console.log &"
```

However, run this way the sbt main thread goes crazy. Here's how I came to that conclusion. I have not yet dug into the sbt codebase, but my blind stab in the dark is that screwing with signals and the shell like this somehow causes bizarre behavior. Any sbt devs have a better educated guess?

1) last lines in the console.log, pretty standard stuff.

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

2) top showing processes, nothing is happening but the cpu load never goes away.

**PID** USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S **%CPU** %MEM    TIME+  **COMMAND**

**14037** hubuser   20   0 8540m 1.6g  25m S **100.0** 10.5   3:39.94 **java**

3) top showing native threads from the same run.

**PID** USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S **%CPU** %MEM    TIME+  **COMMAND**

**14044** hubuser   20   0 8540m 1.6g  25m R **100.0** 10.5  15:14.45 **java**

4) finally, the salient part of the thread dump. 0x36dc = 14044

```
kill -3 14037

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fdbb400a800 nid=0x36dc runnable [0x00007fdbbaf76000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:210)
    at jline.Terminal.readCharacter(Terminal.java:99)
    at jline.UnixTerminal.readVirtualKey(UnixTerminal.java:122)
    at jline.ConsoleReader.readVirtualKey(ConsoleReader.java:1606)
    at play.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.waitEOF$1(PlayInteractionMode.scala:29)
    at play.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$$anonfun$waitForKey$1.apply$mcV$sp(PlayInteractionMode.scala:36)
    at play.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.doWithoutEcho(PlayInteractionMode.scala:41)
    at play.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.waitForKey(PlayInteractionMode.scala:36)
    at play.PlayConsoleInteractionMode$.waitForCancel(PlayInteractionMode.scala:45)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$createPlayRunCommand$1$$anonfun$57.apply(PlayCommands.scala:671)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$createPlayRunCommand$1$$anonfun$57.apply(PlayCommands.scala:523)
    at scala.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:533)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$createPlayRunCommand$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:523)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$createPlayRunCommand$1.apply(PlayCommands.scala:497)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$sbt$Command$$apply1$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Command.scala:72)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:90)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.State$$anon$2.process(State.scala:171)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:64)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:53)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:50)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:50)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:33)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:13)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That stack trace leads me to believe you are spinning on the console/tty trying to read input.  Or perhaps from a file.    My recollection of Sbt is that it doesn't support multiple commands at once from the command line (compile and run).   You have run all these as separate commands and it works?  How about putting into a script and exec'ing that.

Comment: It does support multiple commands, but I believe the syntax being used doesn't do what he things it does.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. As Bob states it is definitely possible to run multiple commands by prefixing with semicolons. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Howto/runningcommands.html

Also, those commands do work as expected if running in the interactive shell. The change to stdin from the background and nohup is certainly a plausible explanation for the loop's confusion.

Comment: One other thing to note, even running this command as is does what I want it to do. I use rsync to create copies of my git repository as well as update changed files pushed to a git remote. This way I can have many compilers running against the same synced source files with unique target directories per compiler. I get all of the hot recompile features I desire from this setup, it just happens a lot slower on account of the unhappy thread.

Comment: Its obviously an IO spin and more so on a terminal from the stack.   Gotta be the nohup.   sbt must be trying to read something from the terminal.   Try redirecting stdin around /dev/null,zero,console and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: I did try redirecting stdin, but to no avail. @Totoro is right that the problem is spinning on IO reading, so I will mark this answer correct. The underlying problem seems to be the jline library the play framework sbt plugin is using to read commands in interactive mode.

I've found a hack that partially solves my problem, but am continuing to look for a better way. For anyone who wants to follow this in greater detail, I have a thread going on the sbt-dev forum.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sbt-dev/IFk61Uj778Y

Answer (score 0):

This has haunted us as well, albeit with a much newer version of sbt/Playframework.

We were experiencing 100% CPU load on one of Playframework threads after upgrading to Java 11 & newest Play (version 2.8.17 running Java 11.0.17). sbt version is 1.6.2. We are using [Tilt](https://tilt.dev/) to keep all the configs in one place as well as for general convenience. One thread with jline/sbt stack trace elements was consuming 100-130% of CPU on Linux all the time while there were no HTTP requests nor any background jobs.

The secret sauce was to add `-Dsbt.ci=true` to the `sbt run ...` command line (the default value for `sbt.ci` is `false`).